# What are some good MySQL debugging tools for php?

Tags: php, mysql, debugging

I'm looking for something like firebug but to monitor & log all the processed MySQL queries with the syntax, processing time, and fetched rows count and size. All that should be printed on the bottom of the page, so it should be something *includable* on the finish of the php code.

I'm not using any frameworks or libraries, just pure PHP and MySQL.

Any tools recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Just use the mysql general log. Create an include file that runs these two queries and display the output of the 2nd one.

```
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have complete access on the MySQl server, or if there're too much databases running there, and that you just want your app logs you could use "mysql proxy". It's a very usefull tools to catch all the communications (so queries as well) between your specific app and the Database. http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy